# Плавное появление и исчезновение блока при прокрутке на чистом javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const scrollUpButton = document.querySelector('.backToTop');

    if (scrollUpButton) {
        scrollUpButton.addEventListener('click', function name() {
            window.scrollTo({
                top: 0,
                behavior: 'smooth',
            });
        });

        window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
            const scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

            if (scrolled >= 800) {
                scrollUpButton.classList.add('backToTop_visible');
            } else {
                scrollUpButton.classList.remove('backToTop_visible');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.backToTop {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #000;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: 60px;
  bottom: 120px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.backToTop::before {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: '';
  background-image: url("../img/sprites/svgSprites.svg#backToTop");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.backToTop:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.backToTop_visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="backToTop page__backToTop icon_backToTop"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может быть так ?

**Смотреть на весь экран**

```js
let body = document.querySelector("body");
let bHeight = body.getBoundingClientRect().height;
let screenY = window.innerHeight / 2;
let btn = document.querySelector("#btn");

window.onscroll = function() {
  if (pageYOffset > screenY) {
    btn.classList.add("fixed");
  } else {
    btn.classList.remove("fixed");
  }
}

btn.onclick = function() {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth',
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
}

section:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}

section:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue;
}

section:nth-child(4) {
  background: pink;
}

section:nth-child(5) {
  background: yellow;
}

#btn {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: 0.34s linear;
}

#btn.fixed {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>

<button id="btn">Вверх</button>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol'  авторшу очевидно что то не устроило

Comment: @Sevastopol' не ответа не комментария - ни чего не сказала что так или нет

Comment: @Sevastopol' и последнее посещение 4 часа назад

Comment: @Sevastopol' авторша была 4 часа назад и ни чего не написала

Comment: @Sevastopol' вот эта ситуация бесит аж - хоть писали бы что не так или криво работает или ваще косячно - но просто молчок

Comment: @MaximLensky Только как новичку в javascript мне не понятен один момент, к данной теме не относиться, но всё же может подскажете:
`window.addEventListener('scroll', function() { });` и `scrollUpButton.addEventListener('click', function name() { });` вы  заменили на `window.onscroll = function() { }` и `btn.onclick = function() { }`, а если у меня в проетке десятки обработчиков `elem.onclick` или `onscroll`, то последней обработчик заменит предыдущие и те перестанут работать, как быть?

Comment: И нужно ли писать `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { });` Также попадается такое `(function () {...})();` что это, для чего ? Обьясните пожалуйста, а то голова кругом?

Comment: @Анастасия я код обработчика скрола взял ваш - остальное там собствено просто плавное появление -

Comment: @Анастасия хотя я весь код не вижу - все обработчики не знаю - из этого я вот так заменил - просто не видя весь код

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107571/discussion-between--and-maximlensky).

Comment: @Sevastopol' спс __ только права модера появились - но это всё уже было у меня раньше

Comment: @Sevastopol' я же удалял аккаунт - этот отъиграл с год назад -